# Refactoring a case class to a non-case class without failing compilation

Tags: scala

Fiddling with [sample code demonstrating type bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html), I changed the original code below from using a case class to a plain class, for the definition of class `MyInt`, the only class in this snippet.

```
trait Similar {
  def isSimilar(x: Any): Boolean
}

class MyInt(x: Int) extends Similar {
  def isSimilar(m: Any): Boolean =
    m.isInstanceOf[MyInt] &&
    m.asInstanceOf[MyInt].x == x
}

object UpperBoundTest extends App {
  def findSimilar[T <: Similar](e: T, xs: List[T]): Boolean =
    if (xs.isEmpty) false
    else if (e.isSimilar(xs.head)) true
    else findSimilar[T](e, xs.tail)
  val list: List[MyInt] = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3))
  println(findSimilar[MyInt](MyInt(4), list))
  println(findSimilar[MyInt](MyInt(2), list))
}
```

That no longer compiles

```
[error] 7: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : MyInt
[error]  required: ?{def x: ?}
[error] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]
[error]  and method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
[error]  are possible conversion functions from MyInt to ?{def x: ?}
[error]     m.asInstanceOf[MyInt].x == x
[error]                   ^
```

This is an interesting case to me, as sometimes I find myself refactoring case classes to plain classes while refactoring inheritance, and clearly some changes need to made in the code in order to enjoy a smooth transition that preserves the code working.

Switching `.AsInstanceOf` to an equivalent match (`m match {case m:MyInt => m.x == x; case _ => false}`) yields the same compilation error. Using a more naive match does not compile either:

```
trait Similar {
  def isSimilar(x: Any): Boolean
}

class MyInt(x: Int) extends Similar {
  def isSimilar(m: Any): Boolean = {
    m match {case m:MyInt => true; case _ => false}
  }
}

object UpperBoundTest extends App {
  val a = new MyInt(4)
  def findSimilar[T <: Similar](e: T, xs: List[T]): Boolean =
    if (xs.isEmpty) false
    else if (e.isSimilar(xs.head)) true
    else findSimilar[T](e, xs.tail)
  val list: List[MyInt] = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3))
  println(findSimilar[MyInt](MyInt(4), list))
  println(findSimilar[MyInt](MyInt(2), list))
}

18: not found: value MyInt
[error]   val list: List[MyInt] = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3))
[error]                                ^
18: not found: value MyInt
[error]   val list: List[MyInt] = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3))
[error]                                          ^
18: not found: value MyInt
[error]   val list: List[MyInt] = List(MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3))
[error]                                                    ^
19: not found: value MyInt
[error]   println(findSimilar[MyInt](MyInt(4), list))
[error]                              ^
20: not found: value MyInt
[error]   println(findSimilar[MyInt](MyInt(2), list))
[error]                              ^
[error] 5 errors found
```

Are non-case classes a practice to be enitrely discouraged other than using them for inheriting them, or when you will never need to check their type? when would you ever use a non-case class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply declare your class as

```
class MyInt(val x: Int) extends Similar
```

For case classes `val` is the default, whereas on regular classes you need to explicitly add it to signal that you want to synthesize the accessors for the constructor parameters

Also, in case classes a companion object providing a default apply method is automatically synthesized, allowing you to call

```
MyInt(2)
```

as opposed to

```
new MyInt(2)
```

You either have to use the latter, or manually provide an apply method in a companion object.

Bottom line, if you need to match on a class, case classes are much more convenient, as you can skip the downcast (which is implicitly performed when you match on the type doing `x: MyInt`)

Classes are not discouraged, simply case-classes are much more convenient in your specific use -case

Comment: Can I still match for the class even if it is not a case class?

Comment: @matt yes, you just need to provide an `unapply` method.

Answer (score 2):

Complete code you need to avoid compilation failure in any case, including pattern matching:

```
class MyInt(val x: Int) extends Similar

object MyInt {
  def apply(x: Int) = new MyInt(x)

  // if more than one field, return Some(tuple of all fields)
  def unapply(myInt: MyInt): Option[Int] = Some(myInt.x)
}
```

If you also want behavior to be the same as original, you need to define `equals` and `hashCode` methods as well:

```
class MyInt(val x: Int) extends Similar {
  def equals(y: Any) = y match {
    case MyInt(z) => x == z
    case _ => false
  }

  def hashCode = x
}
```